# Vim won't open unless I Ctrl+C

Tags: linux, linux-arch

Having this strange problem, where when I do

```sh
vim ...some_file...
```

The shell will freeze until I send a signal `<Ctrl + C>`, and then the `vim` opens up properly.

I haven't touched anything (`.vimrc`, `.bashrc`), so not sure what's happening.

I did upgrade my kernel (and system) today to `5.9.16-1-MANJARO` and Vim to:

```sh
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 09 2021 23:51:55)
Included patches: 1-2489
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.
```

**EDIT**: Even if I do

```sh
vim ...some_file...
```

And then do `<Ctrl+Z>` and then `fg`, it will still hang until I send the signal `<Ctrl+C>`. I haven't done any kernel hacking, either.

Comment: Perhaps [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@D.Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble), turns out the problem was in some `opam` configs in `.vimrc`.

Perhaps something's inconsistent with `opam 2.0.8`, kernel `5.9.16`, and `vim 8.2`.